# How to get the value of one label field into another page in selenium automation

Tags: java

I need value of a label field set in a pom class into another another class.How will i acheive this.

value is storing in orderid.I need to use this order id in another pom class for automationg another test case.Kindly llok into this.

```
public void AddSalesOrder() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Sales Order"));
        salesOrder.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String js1 = "arguments[0].style.display='block';arguments[0].click();";
        js.executeScript(js1, customerName);
        Select select = new Select(customerName);
        select.selectByVisibleText("LLH HOSPITAL AL MUSSAFAH LLC");
        if (blockAlert.isDisplayed()) {
            blockAlert.click();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            r.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)");
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(itemNameSelect));
        itemNameSelect.click();
        String js2 = "arguments[0].style.display='block';arguments[0].click();";
        js.executeScript(js2, baseUOM);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(mattresSelect));
        mattresSelect.click();
        Select sel=new Select(baseUOM);
        sel.selectByVisibleText("PCS");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
         blockAlert.click();
         quantity.sendKeys("1");
        addItem.click();        
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        String netAmtRec=totAmt.getText();
        saveButton.click(); 
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(blockAlert));
        blockAlert.click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        WebElement netAmt=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableId']//tbody/tr[1]/td[5]"));
        String netAmtRec2=netAmt.getText();
        WebElement orderIdRec=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableId']//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));
        orderid=orderIdRec.getText();
        System.out.println("orderid2"+orderid);
        if(netAmtRec.equals(netAmtRec2))
        {
             Reporter.log("Sales Order Saved succesfully", true);
             Reporter.log("showed Net Amount is matching with listed Amount as"+netAmtRec, true);
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(netAmtRec, netAmtRec2, "Test case Passed");

        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

i need this order id in another method in another pom class as below.

```
public void AddDeliveryNote() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Delivery Note"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String js1 = "arguments[0].style.display='block';arguments[0].click();";
        js.executeScript(js1, customerName);
        Select select = new Select(customerName);
        select.selectByVisibleText("LLH HOSPITAL AL MUSSAFAH LLC");
        if (blockAlert.isDisplayed()) {
            blockAlert.click();
        }
        SalesOrder order=new SalesOrder(driver);
        String newOrderId=order.returnOrderId();
        System.out.println(newOrderId);enter code here
        salesID.sendKeys(newOrderId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Well you can return this value and invoke this method in another when you want your orderId. Or you can make a class variable then you can take it wherever you want inside this class